# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory while Using Crawler4j

Tags: java, exception, crawler4j

i am using Crawler4j Example code but i found that i got an exception.

Here is my exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory
    at LocalDataCollectorController.main(LocalDataCollectorController.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory
```

Here is my code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String root Folder = "D:\\";
            int numberOfCrawlers = 5;
            System.out.println("numberOfCrawlers"+numberOfCrawlers);
            System.out.println(rootFolder);

          CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
            config.setCrawlStorageFolder(rootFolder);
            config.setMaxPagesToFetch(10);
            config.setPolitenessDelay(1000);

              PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
           RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
            RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

            controller.addSeed("http://www.ohloh.net/p/crawler4j");
            controller.start(LocalDataCollectorCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);

            List<Object> crawlersLocalData = controller.getCrawlersLocalData();
            long totalLinks = 0;
            long totalTextSize = 0;
            int totalProcessedPages = 0;
            for (Object localData : crawlersLocalData) {
                    CrawlStat stat = (CrawlStat) localData;
                    totalLinks += stat.getTotalLinks();
                    totalTextSize += stat.getTotalTextSize();
                    totalProcessedPages += stat.getTotalProcessedPages();
            }
           System.out.println("Aggregated Statistics:");
            System.out.println("   Processed Pages: " + totalProcessedPages);
            System.out.println("   Total Links found: " + totalLinks);
            System.out.println("   Total Text Size: " + totalTextSize);
    }

}
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with your classpath, not your code...

Answer (score 5):

Download the [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and add it to your build path.

There is also a package which contains all crawler4j dependencies in the [download section](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/downloads/list). You should use this to avoid further problems.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for `NoClassDefFoundError` is always the same: you didn't supply the dependency class during runtime execution. In other words, when you ran your example, you didn't put HttpClient's JAR-file on the classpath. Do this and the problem will go away.